# Is there a way to prevent the transition animation for the first page of bricks?

Tags: angularjs, masonry

Is there a way to prevent the transition animation for the first page of bricks? I like the animation for resizing and appending but I would like the first page of bricks to appear in place without the animation.

I explored using the layoutComplete event but it gets triggered multiple times.

```
<div ng-controller="AppsCtrl" masonry masonry-options="{ transitionDuration: '0.4s' }">
    <div ng-repeat="app in Apps" class="masonry-brick">
        <div id="{{app.id}}" class="sz-card sz-app md-whiteframe-2dp">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="sz-card-image">
                    <div class="sz-app-image"><img src="../../app/images/{{app.imageFile}}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sz-card-details">
                    <div class="sz-card-name">{{app.name}}</div>
                    <div class="sz-card-settings"><md-icon>&#xE8B8;</md-icon></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div scroll-trigger="loadMore()" threshold="100"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-cloak

```
<div ng-controller="AppsCtrl" ng-cloak ....
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: That doesn't appear to have changed the transition.

Comment: If you add it to the ng-repeat tag?